# How to change date format in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, seconds

I have the dates with seconds like this `01.03.2019  12:29:15.9999` and I would like to remove the point after the seconds, so that `01.03.2019  12:29:15.9999` could become `01.03.2019  12:29:16` or `01.03.2019  12:29:15`. I have tried to convert the strings of dates into datetime like `df['DATE']=pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])` but don't know how to solve the seconds issue, to remove the numbers after the point.

Comment: You can use `df.DATE.dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`  or `df.DATE.dt.round("S")`

Answer (score -1):

```py
>>> pd.to_datetime('01.03.2019  12:29:15.9999'[:-5], format ='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
Timestamp('2019-03-01 12:29:15')
```

As an easy approach.

Or, to keep the format, try this:

```
>>> '01.03.2019  12:29:15.9999'[:-5]
'01.03.2019  12:29:15'
```